# SummaryBox and Recursion

Tags: output-formatting, recursion, boxes, object-oriented

How can I make it so that what is under the dropdown block is not calculated/constructed at once? Example code:

```
child = MyObj[<|"Name" -> "Zlata", "Parent" :> parent|>];
parent = MyObj[<|"Name" -> "Kirill", "Child" :> child|>];

MyObj /: 
 MakeBoxes[object : MyObj[data_], 
  form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := 
 Module[{above, below}, 
  above = {{BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", data["Name"]}], 
     SpanFromLeft}};
  below = 
   KeyValueMap[{BoxForm`SummaryItem[{#1 <> ": ", #2}], 
       SpanFromLeft} &]@KeyDrop[data, {"Name"}];
  BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[MyObj, object, data["Icon"], above, below,
    form, "Interpretable" -> Automatic]]
```

Because the objects in the code above refer to each other, there is a recursion-related error when trying to print and display them. How can I avoid this error? I gave a simplified example, but in my work I often make the internal association keys are functions that are parameterized by other objects. So just checking that there is an object on the right side of the rule will not solve the problem.

I want a result that works like the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: This style will cause you all sorts of pain. I suggest you completely rethink your data model. I know that's not what your question is about, but even if you do solve this specific problem, you will just continue wrestling with this forever. The most direct (but sort of hack-ish) way to improve this would be to use some sort of identifier rather than references to the actual objects. So, each of your objects would have an id, which could be a simple string, and references would use these strings.

Comment: A more sophisticated way would be to create separate mappings for the relationships. A parent-child map could be a simple list of pairs of parent-child objects. You could roll it up into an Association or some other structure for better Lookup functionality.

Comment: @lericr functionally - I don't really use symbol-object references. You're right about that. But it doesn't matter if it's a link, an object with a character-association inside or a UUID string - anyway when displayed as a SummaryBox there will be recursion, which I don't know how to limit in the SummaryBox itself.

Comment: removing the recursion from the summary box would be as simple as removing the line starting `below = ....`.  This code reads like it is purposefully trying to make a recursive summary box.

Comment: You wouldn't need to "limit recursion" if you used a different model. My point is that the problem you're facing here with SummaryBox will recur repeatedly as you try to work with this model. Maybe your plan is to embed semantics implicitly in your symbol names, and I suppose that might get you somewhere, but it's just very awkward and brittle.

Comment: @lericr maybe I didn't formulate my problem accurately enough. It's not about the model itself that I'm using, it's just about how you can implement a way to display objects that have looped references. The exact same situation would be in the debugger visual studio if you look at what the variable storing the DateTime structure looks like. There are looped references where a field stores a reference to an object of its parent, but it looks correct. At the same time, it can take quite a long time to expand the field tree.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
myObj /: 
 MakeBoxes[object : myObj[data_], 
  form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := 
 Module[{above, below}, 
  above = {{BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", data["Name"]}], 
     SpanFromLeft}};
  foo = below = KeyValueMap[
      Function[, {BoxForm`SummaryItem[
         {#1 <> ": ",
          HoldForm@#2 /. _myObj ->
           "myObj"["\[LeftSkeleton]\[RightSkeleton]"]}], 
        SpanFromLeft},
       HoldAll] (* this is the important change *)
      ]@KeyDrop[data, {"Name"}];
  BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[myObj, object, data["Icon"], above, below,
    form, "Interpretable" -> Automatic]]

child = myObj[<|"Name" -> "Zlata", "Icon" -> Rasterize["Z"], 
    "Parent" :> parent|>];
parent = 
  myObj[<|"Name" -> "Kirill", "Icon" -> Rasterize["K"], 
    "Child" :> child|>];

parent
```

[image]

```
parent /. HoldPattern[child] -> child
```

[image]

The last example shows that if there's `myObj[]` inside, it will not be typeset by `MakeBoxes[]`. It is replaced with an abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple way - just don't use SummaryBox Item. It doesn't look as nice, but it lets you see all the properties of the object by clicking on the dropdown box

child = MyObj[<|"Name" -> "Zlata", "Parent" -> parent|>];
parent = MyObj[<|"Name" -> "Kirill", "Child" -> child|>];

```
MyObj /: 
 MakeBoxes[object : MyObj[data_], 
  form : (StandardForm | TraditionalForm)] := Module[{above, below},
  above = {{BoxForm`SummaryItem[{"Name: ", data["Name"]}], 
     SpanFromLeft}};
  below = Normal@KeyDrop[data, {"Name"}];
  (*Return*)
  BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox[MyObj, object, Null, above, below, form, 
   "Interpretable" -> Automatic]
  ]
```

[image]